# "Unexpected end of form" post man error while using multer middleware Node js

Tags: node.js, middleware, multer

**back-end:**

```js
import multer from "multer";

const upload = multer({ dest: "upload" });
router.route("/register").post(upload.single("file"), register);`
```

**front-end:**

```js
const signUpHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const myForm = new FormData();

    myForm.append("name", name);
    myForm.append("email", email);
    myForm.append("password", password);
    myForm.append("file", file);

    if (!check) {
    alert("Enter all the fields carefully!");
    } else {
    try {
       dispatch(setLoading(true));
        const { data } = await axios.post(
          `${url}/register`,
          myForm,
          {
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": `multipart/form-data; `,
            },
          }
        );
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
  };
```

I was expecting a file in `req.file` in the register function after the multer middleware but whenever I am sending a request to the URL postman is giving me the same error.

Comment: Does it work if you omit the `headers` from `axios.post`? Because a `FormData` as body sets them implicitly.

Comment: Please include the code where you get the `file` variable